# Password protected excel sheets in Python ( Alternative to win32 package)

Tags: python, excel, winapi, pywin32, xlrd

Is there any package (not win32 for windows) through which I can deal with password protected excel sheets. I have literally tried all the solution for **win32api** but it is not working for me.

> import win32api, sys, os
>
> DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application.

I am asking for an alternative solution to deal with password protected files in excel? All the solution I have found so far suggests me to use win32 but unfortunately it is not working.

EDIT - Issue Resolved. See the below solution

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.

Step 1 : Initially check what bit of python you are using?

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
```

Step 2: Download the relevant files from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Step 3: Install the file and check whether you are getting any error for

```
import win32com
```

I wrongly download 64bit python files whereas my platform architecture is 32 bit.